# Using subquery's alias elsewhere in the SELECT table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of prices that doctors charge for medical procedures within a region. I'd like to compare each doctor's price (`average_submitted_charge_amount`) to the average price using a subquery.

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT Avg(average_submitted_chrg_amt) AS average 
    FROM    medicare 
    ) AS peerAverage, 
( ( average_submitted_chrg_amt - peerAverage.average ) / peeraverage.average 
) AS charge_deviation 
FROM medicare
```

MySQL throws an error: `Unknown column 'peerAverage' in 'field list'`. Is referencing a subquery by alias elsewhere within the query not allowed?

Comment: You are trying to access `average` as if it was a field in a table named `peerAverage`, but it's not. The `average` alias is not availabe outside the subquery as you give the subquery value the alias `peerAverage`. Try using just `peerAverage` instead of `peerAverage.average` and it might have a possibility to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the calculation to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT m.*, peerAverage
      ((average_submitted_chrg_amt - peerAverage) / peeraverage
      ) AS charge_deviation 
FROM medicare m cross join
     (SELECT Avg(average_submitted_chrg_amt)  AS peerAverage 
      FROM medicare 
     ) const;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parentheses ")" more:

Try:

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT Avg(average_submitted_chrg_amt) AS average 
    FROM    medicare 
    ) AS peerAverage, 
( ( average_submitted_chrg_amt - peerAverage.average ) / peeraverage.average 
) AS charge_deviation 
FROM medicare
```

To help you more, post the tables.